# TCP sequence number smaller than initial sequence number (the one received in TCP SYN)

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols, rfc

If the server receives the TCP sequence number that is smaller than the sequence number sent in TCP SYN from client. what does TCP server do in this case?

May be this is not possible but due to some bug if this happens, how would server behave?

Here assume that TCP sequence number hasn't overflown.

Answer (score 2):

A segment with such a sequence number will be well outside the receive window (case 4 from the table below):

From [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.3):

> There are four cases for the acceptability test for an incoming
> segment:
>
> ```
> Segment Receive  Test
> Length  Window
> ------- -------  -------------------------------------------
>
>    0       0     SEG.SEQ = RCV.NXT
>
>    0      >0     RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>
>   >0       0     not acceptable
>
>   >0      >0     RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>               or RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ+SEG.LEN-1 < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
> ```

What should TCP do with such a segment?

> If an incoming segment is not acceptable, an acknowledgment
> should be sent in reply (unless the RST bit is set, if so drop
> the segment and return):
>
> ```
> <SEQ=SND.NXT><ACK=RCV.NXT><CTL=ACK>
> ```
>
> After sending the acknowledgment, drop the unacceptable segment
> and return.

So TCP will send an Ack, and drop the invalid segment it received.

Comment: Thanks Malt, so ack will be sent with acknowledgement no. which was sent last(the next expected sequence number from client ), right?

Comment: Yes, that's what the RFC says.

Comment: However, note that there are sometimes differences in practice, between RFCs and actual implementations. A specific TCP implementation might chose to do something else, or simply have a bug in it. So it's hard to guarantee anything.